# Django model inheritance using mptt

Tags: django, models, mptt

I'm bulding a model with nested tree classification. A vocabulary `Entity` is inherited from an abstract base class `TreeVocabulary`. There is also a class `SpecialEntity`, which inherits from `Entity`. In `SpecialEntity` there should be few additional fields.

`Entity` and `SpecialEntity` should both be trees, for which I use mptt http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/. In `Entity` there should be a record, which has children in the `SpecialEntity` (those children are root elements in the `SpecialEntity`).

This is how i imagine this:

```
class Vocabulary(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=300)
    order= models.IntegerField(default=100)
    class Meta:
        abstract= True

class SpecialType(Vocabulary):

class TreeVocabulary(MPTTModel):
    parent= TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='children', limit_choices_to=Q(parent__isnull=True))
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by= ('name',)
    class Meta:
        abstract= True

class Entity(TreeVocabulary):

class SpecialEntity(Entity):
    code= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type= models.ForeignKey(SpecialType)
    class Meta:
        ordering= ('code',)
```

Now, the problem is that for some reason `SpecialEntity` escapes mptt: `sqlall` shows a plain table without `parent_id` in it. Although it's present in `Entity`, which directly inherits from `TreeVocabulary`.

Is it a bug in django-mptt? Or maybe it is a bad design?
I'm not asking to design it for me, but rather to point in the right direction

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can not see you inherit `MPTTModel` anywhere. [It is necessarily](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/tutorial.html#set-up-your-model)

Comment: ops, sorry, you right, sorry. i have changed the code according to my changes, but unfortunately the problem remains

Comment: yes, you right, sorry for that. i've changed the code in my question, but the problem remained unsolved:
`CREATE TABLE "vocabulary_specialentity" (
    
    "entity_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "vocabulary_entity" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    
    "code" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    
    "type_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "vocabulary_specialtype" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    
)`

Comment: Did you migrate your tables? If your updates to the code are not just a typo fix - you should sync your database with code.

Comment: yes, i did - no effect. so, now i have TreeVocabulary inherited from MPTTModel, Entity inherited from TreeVocabulary, and SpecialEntity - from Entity. in Entity there's a full package (parent_id, left, right, level, etc.), while in SpecialEntity there are only id, code, and foreign key to type_id

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering my own question after a short investigation.

Multi-table inheritance is possible in mptt, but all mptt fields (parent, lft, rght, level, etc.) for any child should be stored in the one (obviously, parent) table.

Taking into consideration the principles of Modified Preorder Tree Traversal, it is reasonable.

For the example in my question in the db there will be created:

- specialtype (plain table)
- entity - tree structure with the mptt fields, containing data for
  both models Entity and SpecialEntity
- specialentity - plain table with foreign key to entity, containing
  only fields specific to SpecialEntity